# What places have the best efficiency for EV training in Black And White?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I've decided to look into EV training to make my Pokemon stronger in a competitive battle.  I know about how to train EVs, using items such as `Macho Brace` or `Power Bracer` etc, but I was wondering what routes/caves/surf areas/other places were best for each specific EV stat.

My version is Pokemon Black, and I've beaten the Elite 4 and Alder and have access to all areas of the game.

I know that on Route 1, all you can find are Lillipup and Patrat, both of which give +1 Attack EV.
That makes for a **100%** chance to get +1 Attack EVs per kill.

I also know that in the cave beside Route 3, all you can find are roggenrola and woobat, which give +1 Defense EV and +1 Speed EV respectively.
This results in only a **50%** chance to get +1 Defense EV per kill, or a **50%** chance to get +1 Speed EV per kill.

I'd like to know where all the statistically most rewarding places to find each EV are, to minimize the time it takes to EV train.
I believe I know already that route 1 is the best for Attack, but I would also like to know about Defense, Special Attack, Special Defense, Speed, and Health.

Comment: Presumably, if there was a route with 50% chance for +1 Attack, and 50% chance for +2 attack, (or something similar) that would be faster than doing Route 1 (albeit requiring more math).

Comment: @RavenDreamer yes, I was thinking the same thing before I posted the question.  Hopefully if someone does find such a route they will add it to their answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### HP

- Surf in Icirrus City - Stunfisk (100%, 2 HP EV)

*Note also, There's Victini (for 3 HP EV) that can be rebattled infinitely as long as it is not caught.*

### Atk

- Route 1 - Lillipup and Patrat (total 100%, 1 Atk EV)
- Dragonspiral Tower 2F - Golett (100%, 1 Atk)
- Dragonspiral Tower 1F - Golett and  Mienfoo (total 70%, 1 Atk), Druddigon (30%, 2 Atk)
- Outside of Dragonspiral Tower, Double Grass - Tranquill, Sawsbuck and Druddigon (total 70%, 2 Atk), and Mienfoo (30%, 1 Atk)

*Note that During Winter, the Double Grass location changes up. notably with Tranquill being replaced by Vanillish (30%, 2 SpAtk).*

### Def

- Wellspring Cave - Roggengola (50%, 1 Def)
- Pinwheel Forest - Venipede and Sewaddle (total 50%, 1 Def)
- Pinwheel Forest Double Grass - Swadloon and Whirlipede (total 50%, 2 Def)
- Chargestone Cave - Klink, Ferroseed and Boldore (59%, 1 Def)

*Note that Boldore also gives 1 Atk in addition to 1 Def!*

### SpAtk

- Celestial Tower - Litwick and Elgyem (100%, 1 SpAtk)

*Note that there is a nurse on 3F of the Celestial Tower*

### SpDef

- Surf in Driftveil City - Frillish (100%, 1 SpDef)

### Speed

- Surf on Route 3 - Basculin (100%, 2 Speed)

*Note loads of places with Surf have 100% Basculin, but this one is reachable from a pokécenter without going trough tall grass.*

([source](http://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/ev-training-spots-in-black-white.101974/))

Comment: Really nice answer, thanks - the note about the nurse particularly useful.